# QuerySyntaxException when trying to validate a table of unclean records to a new table with clean data. Necessary to map entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I have an unclean UncleanRecord tbl with dirty and unvalidated data.
My plan is to go through all the records in the tbl, and then clean and validate it to add into my new CleanRecord tbl.

I am using Spring Batch with Hibernate. When I execute the job, it returned these error:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep  - Encountered an error executing step step1 in job validate
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UNCLEANRECORD is not mapped [SELECT name, contact,address FROM UNCLEANRECORD WHERE date is null]
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UNCLEANRECORD is not mapped
```

I have entity UncleanRecord, and CleanRecord.
With the error in console log, I suppose that I need to map UncleanRecord to CleanRecord? However, the data in Unclean is inconsistent--- there is also no unique identifiers in UncleanRecords... it's purely to store whatever data that is passed into the application. The rows in UncleanRecord would be checked against CleanRecord before being added into CleanRecord

Is it possible to achieve what I want to without Hibernate mapping?

I understand I can do the above with RowMapper<>, however, I am using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a HQL/JPQL query which requires an entity named `UNCLEANRECORD` to exists but it doesn't. I don't know how spring-batch works, but it looks like you should mark the query as being a native query instead.